# WiFi Sometimes Won't Connect on Startup

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm currently running the latest version of Windows 10 (and this has been a problem through several updates of Windows 10). Sometimes, my computer will not connect to WiFi on startup no matter what, because it cannot detect any networks. What I need to do is completely turn off WiFi on my computer, and then turn it back on and it detects the networks that are present. My computer is fast, so it should be connected to WiFi the second I sign in (everything else is loaded by then), but instead this is a 1-2 minute process most of the times that I turn my computer on (sometimes it does detect a network and connects right away). This was not a problem with my WiFi card before I changed my motherboard, RAM, and CPU, but once I made that change this became a common occurrence. I've gone into device manager and uninstalled the device (and it subsequently installed a new driver) but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

"I changed my motherboard, RAM, and CPU"
You probably need to reinstall windows from scratch to get ride of this forever.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes windows automatically turns of wifi adapter to save some power. You can stop that. Go to device manager. Now expand Network adapters. Then right click your network adapter and click Properties. Then clear Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power. Now click OK. If it does not works, run network troubleshooter. I myself got rid of this problem by taking these steps.